# How Can I Replace Any Line by Its Line Number?

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

**EDIT:** After great help from @aschipfl, the code is %110 as functional as I wanted it to be! I did some extra research and made it easy to use with prompts for that extra %10 :P

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Create a prompt to set the variables
set /p _FILETYPE="What file type: "
set /p _LINENUM="Which line: "
set /p _NEWLINE="Make line say: "

rem // Start the loop, and set the files
for %%f in (*%_FILETYPE%) do (
  set "_FILE=%%f"
  echo "_FILE=%%f"

rem // To execute seperate code before the end of the loop, starting at ":subroutine".
call :subroutine "%%f"
)

:subroutine
rem // Write to a temporary file:
> "%_FILE%.new" (
    rem /* Loop through each line of the original file,
    rem    preceded by the line number and a colon `:`:*/
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Store the current line with prefix to a variable:
        set "LN=%%A"
        rem /* Store the line number into another variable;
        rem    everything up to the first non-numeric char. is regarded,
        rem    which is the aforementioned colon `:` in this situation: */
        set /A "NUM=LN"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Compare current line number with predefined one and replace text
        rem    in case of equality, or return original text otherwise: */
        if !NUM! equ %_LINENUM% (
            echo(!_NEWLINE!
        ) else (
            rem // Remove line number prefix:
            echo(!LN:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Move the edited file onto the original one:
move /Y "%_FILE%.new" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**
Doesn't matter whats in any of the lines already. I just want to be able to pick any line from a .txt and replace it with whatever I choose.

So for example: Maybe I have a bunch of .txt's, and I want to replace line 5 in all of them with "vanilla". And later choose to replace line 10 of all .txt's with "Green". And so on...

I've seen lots of people asking the same main question. But I keep finding situational answers.
"How do I replace specific lines?" "you search for whats already in the line, and replace it with your new text" -I cant have that. I need it to be dynamic, because whats in each "line 5" is different, or there's lots of other lines with the same text.

I had tried the only one answer I could find, but all it ended up doing is replace literally all lines with "!ln:*:=!", instead of echoing.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

set "file=yourFile.txt"
set "newLine5=NewLine5Here"

>"%file%.new" (
  for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do for /f "delims=:" %%N in ("%%A") do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal enabableDelayedExpansion
    if "!ln:~0,6!" equ "5:FMOD" (echo(!newLine5!) else echo(!ln:*:=!
    endlocal
  )
)
move /y "%file%.new" "%file%" >nul
```

Comment: If I got it right, the condition `if "!ln:~0,6!" equ "5:FMOD"` should be replaced by `if %%N equ 5`, and there is a typo in `EnableDelayedExpansion`, that's it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following (commented) code should work for you:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=yourFile.txt"
set "_NEWLINE=NewLine5Here"
set /A "_LINENUM=5" & rem // (target line number)

rem // Write to a temporary file:
> "%_FILE%.new" (
    rem /* Loop through each line of the original file,
    rem    preceded by the line number and a colon `:`:*/
    for /F "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /N "^" "%_FILE%"') do (
        rem // Store the current line with prefix to a variable:
        set "LN=%%A"
        rem /* Store the line number into another variable;
        rem    everything up to the first non-numeric char. is regarded,
        rem    which is the aforementioned colon `:` in this situation: */
        set /A "NUM=LN"
        rem // Toggle delayed expansion to avoid trouble with `!`:
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        rem /* Compare current line number with predefined one and replace text
        rem    in case of equality, or return original text otherwise: */
        if !NUM! equ %_LINENUM% (
            echo(!_NEWLINE!
        ) else (
            rem // Remove line number prefix:
            echo(!LN:*:=!
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
rem // Move the edited file onto the original one:
move /Y "%_FILE%.new" "%_FILE%"

endlocal
exit /B
```

Besides the typo in `EnableDelayedExpansion` in your code, you do not even need a second `for /F` loop to get the line number, and you do not need to extract a certain number of characters from the prefixed line text.

Note that this approach fails for line numbers higher than 2<sup>31</sup> - 1 = 2 147 483 647.

Comment: Oh my goodness, thank you so much! Finally an answer!
Do you think there's a way this can be kicked up a notch, and run through every file in a folder? That is ofcourse aside the batch itself :P

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, you could wrap around a [`for` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html), so that %_FILE%` becomes replaced by the loop meta-variable; the question is whether the line number to replace and the replacement text are the same for all files; anyway, let me suggest that you give itvs try and in case of troubles just ask a new question...

Comment: That is right, the replacement text needs be the same. I tried getting it to loop, and it did function perfectly when setting just the variables. But when trying to include the rest of the code after the "move file", it fails and aborts. Gut says its an indention problem. But I wouldn't know.

That is: 
```for %%f in (*.txt) do (
  set "_FILE=%%f"......move /Y "%_FILE%.new" "%_FILE%"
)```

Comment: Scratch that, I fixed it by executing the rest of the code as a subroutine :P

Answer (score 0):

> ...is replace literally all lines with "!ln:*:=!", instead of echoing.

But that's correct, because the `FINDSTR /N` prefixes each line with a line number before.
The `!ln:*:=!` only removes the line number again.
And the `findstr` trick is used to avoid skipping of empty lines or lines beginning with `;` (the EOL character).

The `!line:*:=!` *replaces* everthing up to the first double colon (and incuding it) with nothing.
This is better than using `FOR "delims=:"` because `delims=:` would also strip double colons at the front of a line.

The toggling of delayed expansion is necessary to avoid accidential stripping of `!` and `^` in the line `set "ln=%%A"`

**To fix your code:**

```
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" "%file%"') do (
    set "ln=%%A"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    if "!ln:~0,6!" equ "5:FMOD" ( 
        set "out=!newLine5!"
    ) else (
        set "out=!ln:*:=!"
    )
    echo(!out!
    endlocal
)
```

Comment: Well no lines were quite replaced with nothing, by it. It was literally replaced with "!ln:*:=!". They all said "!ln:*:=!".

But I understand what your saying. Either way, I guess that chunk of code isnt something I need work with. But I do need something nonetheless.

Comment: @LethalDumpster That's because you have to disable the DelayedExpansion
 before you enter the FOR and you have a typo in "setlocal enab**able**DelayedExpansion". I added a fix

Comment: Im getting "FINDSTR: Cannot open". Maybe im using this wrong. The batch file is in a folder with nothing else but a "test.txt". Apologies for my ignorance. Im practically less than novice. I just need a tool for work.

Comment: @LethalDumpster Did you `set file=test.txt`? Or modify it directly to `findstr /n "^" "test.txt"`

Comment: Both actually. Although without the removal of percentages. Done, I'm no longer being given an error. But i'm not seeing line 5 change. This is what it shows as in CMD ```(
set "ln=5:Replace Me"
 setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 if "!ln:~0,6!" EQU "5:FMOD" (set "out=!newLine5!" )  else (set "out=!ln:*:=!" )
 echo(!out!
 endlocal
)
Replace Me```

Comment: Currently you only replace line 5 when it begins with (including line number) `5:FMOD`, if you only want to search for the line number you should look at aschipfl's comment or change `IF "!ln:~0,2!" equ "5:" (`

Comment: Well ofcourse that's what I wanted. As stated in the original post, the contents of line 5 cannot be specified. As each use of line 5 between files is different. Ofcourse the code that I've posted is different from that goal. But I only posted it to show what all I could scrounge from online. I wouldn't know what it does other than what others say it does. Thankyou though, the efforts are greatly appreciated. I'll continue at a later time.